# DRF simple jwt. How to change response from TokenObtainPairView to get an access token EXPIRES time

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I wrote in urls:

```py
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
    TokenRefreshView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    ...
]
```

Then when I request api/token/, I got a json response with only **access and refresh** tokens.
But I need to get also an **access token expires time** for saving it to localStorage and request to the refresh url, save the new access token in the storage if the time was expired

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. One way to solve this problem is to have new serializers for access and refresh APIs, like:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer, TokenRefreshSerializer

from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

class TokenObtainLifetimeSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)
        refresh = self.get_token(self.user)
        data['lifetime'] = int(refresh.access_token.lifetime.total_seconds())
        return data


class TokenRefreshLifetimeSerializer(TokenRefreshSerializer):

    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)
        refresh = RefreshToken(attrs['refresh'])
        data['lifetime'] = int(refresh.access_token.lifetime.total_seconds())
        return data
```

And also add new views for that as well like:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenViewBase
from accounts.api.serializers import TokenObtainLifetimeSerializer, TokenRefreshLifetimeSerializer


class TokenObtainPairView(TokenViewBase):
    """
        Return JWT tokens (access and refresh) for specific user based on username and password.
    """
    serializer_class = TokenObtainLifetimeSerializer


class TokenRefreshView(TokenViewBase):
    """
        Renew tokens (access and refresh) with new expire time based on specific user's access token.
    """
    serializer_class = TokenRefreshLifetimeSerializer
```

and finally add new views to your urls like:

```
from django.urls import path

from accounts.api.views import TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView
urlpatterns = [
    path('token/obtain/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token-obtain'),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token-refresh'),
]
```

Now despite of those tokens of yours, you also have expire times in both of your APIs.

Comment: do you maybe know how to send a profile_image back with the response?